# scrollEnabled inside Outer UIScrollView's scrollViewDidScroll requires two swipe

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, nestedscrollview

I have *UICollectionView* inside *UITableViewCell*. I wanted to enable or disable scrolling of *UICollectionView* and *UITableView* based on contentOffset of both. For example, inside UICollectionView's ViewController I have a code -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        _collectionView.scrollEnabled = false;
        // This will enable _tableView scroll which is implemented in UITableView's ViewController
        [_delegate toggleScroll:true];

    } else {
        _collectionView.scrollEnabled = true;
       // This will disable _tableView scroll which is implemented in UITableView's ViewController
        [_delegate toggleScroll:false];
    }

}
```

But enabling the scroll does not effect immediately. First scroll does not enable or disable *_collectionView* but on second scroll it works as expected. Can't we enable the scroll on the fly(Only on one swipe/scroll)?

Answer (score 0):

`scrollViewDidScroll` get called back and forth for bouncing animation of collection view. For that reason once its setting `scrollEnabled = false` after animation its setting `scrollEnabled = true`.
Try to check in a range like 0 to 10 or some threshold value.

Or you can try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 10) {
        _collectionView.scrollEnabled = false;

    } else {
        _collectionView.scrollEnabled = true;

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but its not because of the threshold value. _collectionView.scrollEnabled = true/false is call instantly but in order to see the effect I need to end the scroll and scroll again. This time it will work as expected.